# Graphing a Circle that Doesn't Intersect the Pole

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles, polar-coordinates

I am trying to graph a circle using a polar equation that does not intersect the pole.  For example the rectangular equation would be $(x-3)^2+(y+2)^2=1$

If I use the usual way to transform this into a polar equation I end up with the equation $r^2=-12+6\cos\theta-4\sin\theta$, and if I take the square root of both sides I get r equal to an imaginary number which can't be graphed in the real plane.  Any suggestions for another way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify just what you mean by "a polar equation." Do you want $r$ expressed as a function of $\theta$? Do you realize that such a function is not possible with many circles, including the one you use as an example, since many values of $\theta$ have two values of $r$ that fit on the circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you replaced $x$ with $r \cos \theta$ and $y$ with $r \sin \theta$ in the equation $(x-3)^2 + (y+2)^2 = 1$ to get $r^2 = -12 + 6 \cos \theta - 4 \sin \theta$. Since $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ take values between -1 and 1, that implicitly assumes that the circle is centered around the origin, whereas your circle is centered around (3,-2).
The correct set of polar equations is
$$
\begin{cases}
x = \cos \theta + 3 \\
y = \sin \theta - 2
\end{cases}
$$

In general, for an equation $(x-x_c)^2 + (y-y_c)^2 = r^2$, the corresponding set of polar equations is
$$
\begin{cases}
x = r \cos \theta + x_c \\
y = r \sin \theta + y_c
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: (+1) for an in depth explanation from a new user :)

Comment: Thanks! This answer assumes of course that the polar coordinate system is centered around $(x_c, y_c)$. If you would want a polar coordinate system centered in the origin, then replace $x^2+y^2$ with $r^2$, replace $x$ with $r \cos \theta$ and $y$ with $r \sin \theta$ to obtain $r^2 - 6 r \cos \theta + 4 r \sin \theta + 12 = 0$, but then $\theta$ does not take all values from $0$ to $2 \pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Correct transformation is
r$^2$ = 6r.sin $\theta$ - 4r.cos $\theta$ - 12.

Comment: this is better, but still mistaken